# How do I sort by alphabetical order this array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
{ExpertiseId: "1Y", ExpertiseName: "Ad-Based Monetization", ExpertiseSubCategory: "Content & Information Services"},
 {ExpertiseId: "2", ExpertiseName: "Balance sheet businesses", ExpertiseSubCategory: null},
 {ExpertiseId: "3", ExpertiseName: "Brand Franchiser or Licenser", ExpertiseSubCategory: "Consumer Brands or IP"},
{ExpertiseId: "4", ExpertiseName: "Branded retail", ExpertiseSubCategory: null},
{ExpertiseId: "5", ExpertiseName: "Wholesale", ExpertiseSubCategory: "Consumer Brands or IP"}
```

How can I sort it by alphabetical order on `ExpertiseSubCategory`

Comment: Please show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: psst... checkout this example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_sort_object1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

A very simple implementation would be:

```
// assuming the array's name to be "exampleArray"
let sortedArray = exampleArray.sort((a, b) => a.ExpertiseSubCategory.localeCompare(b.ExpertiseSubCategory))
```